# count repeat of every word

Tags: java

I want to write a code that count repeat of every word in a string,words separate each other with some character that input as a string...why my code don't work?
please answer soon!

```
public class repeat {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ss = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please write a string:");
    String s = ss.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please write a character:");
    String w = ss.nextLine();
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int y=0;
    for (i=0 ;i < s.length() ;i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < w.length(); j++) {
            if (w.charAt(j) == s.charAt(i) && i!=y && i!=0 && i!=s.length() -1 ) {
                k += 1;
                y=i+1;
            }
        }
    }
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    y = 0;
    int r = 0;
    k++;
    System.out.println(k);
   String[] a = new String[k];
    for (r=0 ;r < k-1 ;r++) {
        for (j=1 ;j < s.length() ;j++) {
            for (i = 1; i < w.length(); i++) {
                if (w.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
                    a[r] = s.substring(y, j);
                    y = j+1;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(a[r]);
    }
    a[k-1] = s.substring(y+1,s.length());
    i = 0;
    int[] b = new int[k];
    while (i <k) {
        b[i] = 0;
        i++;
    }
    i = j = 0;
    while (i < k) {
        while (j != i && j < k) {
            if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                a[j] = null;
                b[i]++;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    i = j = 0;
    while (i < k) {
        if (a[i] != null) {
            System.out.println(a[i] + " " + b[i]);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Protip, avoid single letter variable names. And always comment when things get densely algorithmic. What error are you getting?

Comment: what's the input, whats the output? Have you tried debugging urgently?

Comment: i start to learn java just one week ago and i dont know how can i debug my code! i get exception error

Answer (score 0):

Looking through your code your taking a very long approach to this problem. The easiest thing to do is use regex https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/. Please see the methods below.

```
public Sentence(String sentanceString) {        
    this.fullSentence = sentanceString;
    breakStringIntoWords(sentanceString);        
}

private void breakStringIntoWords(String sentanceString) {
    String[] wordsInString = sentanceString.split("\\W+");
    for (String word : wordsInString) {
        words.add(new Word(word));
    }
}
```

In the second method I broke a sentence (delimited by [spaces]) into words. From here you would write code to compare each word (a class that has a to string method so treat it as a string) to every other word in the Words array list, be careful to avoid over counting.

Answer (score 0):

**(Wrong language i did it wrongly in c# - see next answer for java)**

I suggest to use array and Split for this because it is very complicated work with substring to seach for the char. While w still is a String, c need to be a type char.

```
        String[] foundwords = { };
        Int32[] wordcount = { };

        foreach (String word in s.Split(w))
        {
            int IndexOfWord = Array.IndexOf(foundwords, word);
            if (IndexOfWord < 0)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref foundwords, foundwords.Length + 1);
                Array.Resize(ref wordcount, wordcount.Length + 1);
                foundwords[foundwords.GetUpperBound(0)] = word;
                wordcount[foundwords.GetUpperBound(0)] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                wordcount[IndexOfWord]++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= foundwords.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Found word '{0}' {1} times.", foundwords[i], wordcount[i]));
        }
```

be aware that it is case sensitive.

Comment: Sorry i was in the wrong programming Language (C#) - i will rewrite for java shortly

Answer (score 0):

ok this is now Java with Split instead of searching the string manually:
I don't exactly know if the copyarray is the best practice to make it larger but if your string is not megabytes large it won't be a problem:

```
public class repeat
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "Hello world this is a very good test to a world just that contains just more words than just hello";
        String w = " ";

        String[] foundwords = new String[0];
        int[] wordcount = new int[0];
        String[] splittext = s.split(w);
        for (int i = 0; i< splittext.length; i++)
        {
            int IndexOfWord = getIndexOfWord(splittext[i], foundwords);
            if (IndexOfWord < 0)
            {
                String[] foundwordsTemp = new String[foundwords.length + 1];
                int[] wordcountTemp = new int[foundwords.length + 1];
                System.arraycopy(foundwords, 0, foundwordsTemp, 0, foundwords.length);
                System.arraycopy(wordcount, 0, wordcountTemp, 0, foundwords.length);
                foundwords = new String[foundwords.length + 1];
                wordcount = new int[wordcount.length + 1];
                System.arraycopy(foundwordsTemp, 0, foundwords, 0, foundwordsTemp.length);
                System.arraycopy(wordcountTemp, 0, wordcount, 0, foundwordsTemp.length);
                foundwords[foundwords.length-1] = splittext[i];
                wordcount[foundwords.length-1] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                wordcount[IndexOfWord]++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < foundwords.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(String.format("Found word '%s' %d times.", foundwords[i], wordcount[i]));
        }
    }
    private static int getIndexOfWord(String word, String[] foundwords)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < foundwords.length; i++)
        {
            if (word.equals(foundwords[i]))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help...but this is my homework and i should solve this with substring...can you help me again?!

Answer (score 0):

so if it is still on your list i made a code.

First - you where lost to just let it run in the main procedure only. You should start and seperate your work into single tasks instead of writing a strait start stop program. Using functions with a "good" name will make it easier to you in future.

**First you need something to find the String in another.**

Usually you may use

```
 int dividerPosition = restString.indexOf(searchString);
```

this is a java build in function. If you want to write it yourself, you could create a function like this (that will do the same but you can "see" it working:)

```
private static int indexOf(String restString, String searchString)
{
    int dividerPosition = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < restString.length()-searchString.length(); i++)
    {
        // Debuging test:
        System.out.println(String.format("search Pos %d in '%s' for length %d.", i, restString, searchString.length()));
        if (restString.substring(i, i + searchString.length()).equals(searchString))
        {
            dividerPosition = i;
            i = restString.length();
        }
    }
    return dividerPosition;
}
```

and use this function in your code later on like:

```
int dividerPosition = indexOf(restString, searchString);
```

**I will again use the function to find either a word is allready known**

```
private static int getIndexOfWord(String word, String[] foundwords)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < foundwords.length; i++)
    {
        if (word.equals(foundwords[i]))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**Third Task would be to Split and count the Words at the found position.**
The easier way (only my opinion) would be just to cut of the found Words from the String - so write a function that will "save" the found word in a array or count the "counter"-Array if it is allready found.

This most important task to understand is important - ok we will just look for the position of the string we are searching. We need to check if it is not found (so the last word)
We will store the found word (that is the part before the found String) in a variable and do the "count or create new word" thing. And then we will return the String cut of the word and the Seach-String.

The Cut-Off is important because we replace the origin String by the one without the first word and just repeat this until the origin String is "".
For the last word we ensure the function will return "" by changing the dividerPosition to the length of the RestString - that is the last word now only - minus "searchString.length()" so it will fit to the return "restString.substring(dividerPosition+searchString.length());" to return ""

Look in the next part into the function named "getNextW("

you can run int with the self-written IndexOf function or the Java function by changing the commentlines in

```
        /// Index Of Search (better)
        //int dividerPosition = restString.indexOf(searchString);

        /// Manual Search (why make it more difficuilt - you should learn to make your work as easy as possible)
        int dividerPosition = indexOf(restString, searchString);
```

**Everything together**

to get startet you will have very little code in the main procedure using the "cut" function until the String is empty - all together now:

```
public class repeat
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "Hello a world a this is a very good test to a a a a world just that contains just more words than just hello";
        String w = " ";

        while (!(s = getNextW(s, w)).equals(""))
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for (int i = 0; i < foundwords.length; i++)
        {
            // Debuging test:
            System.out.println(String.format("Found word '%s' %d times.", foundwords[i], wordcount[i]));
        }
    }
    private static String[] foundwords = new String[0];
    private static int[] wordcount = new int[0];

    private static String getNextW(String restString, String searchString)
    {

        /// Index Of Search (better)
        //int dividerPosition = restString.indexOf(searchString);

        /// Manual Search (why make it more difficuilt - you should learn to make your work as easy as possible)
        int dividerPosition = indexOf(restString, searchString);

        String foundWord;
        if (dividerPosition > 0)
        {
            foundWord = restString.substring(0, dividerPosition);
        }
        else
        {
            foundWord = restString;
            dividerPosition = restString.length()-searchString.length();
        }
        int IndexOfWord = getIndexOfWord(foundWord, foundwords);
        if (IndexOfWord < 0)
        {
            String[] foundwordsTemp = new String[foundwords.length + 1];
            int[] wordcountTemp = new int[foundwords.length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(foundwords, 0, foundwordsTemp, 0, foundwords.length);
            System.arraycopy(wordcount, 0, wordcountTemp, 0, foundwords.length);
            foundwords = new String[foundwords.length + 1];
            wordcount = new int[wordcount.length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(foundwordsTemp, 0, foundwords, 0, foundwordsTemp.length);
            System.arraycopy(wordcountTemp, 0, wordcount, 0, foundwordsTemp.length);
            foundwords[foundwords.length-1] = foundWord;
            wordcount[foundwords.length-1] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            wordcount[IndexOfWord]++;
        }
        // Debuging test:
        System.out.println(String.format("Rest of String is '%s' positionnext is %d.", restString, dividerPosition));
        return restString.substring(dividerPosition+searchString.length());
    }
    private static int getIndexOfWord(String word, String[] foundwords)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < foundwords.length; i++)
        {
            if (word.equals(foundwords[i]))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    private static int indexOf(String restString, String searchString)
    {
        int dividerPosition = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < restString.length()-searchString.length(); i++)
        {
            // Debuging test:
            System.out.println(String.format("search Pos %d in '%s' for length %d.", i, restString, searchString.length()));
            if (restString.substring(i, i + searchString.length()).equals(searchString))
            {
                dividerPosition = i;
                i = restString.length();
            }
        }
        return dividerPosition;
    }
}
```

Other variant with charAt and im am using your kind of "count words to size the array" what will result in a to big array (potentially far to big):

```
public class repeat
{
    private static String[] foundwords;
    private static int[] wordcount;
    private static int counter;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Hello a world a this is a very good test to a a a a world just that contains just more words than just hello";
        String w = " ";
        int tempPos = 0;
        counter = 1; // counting total w-strings+1 for dim
        while ((tempPos = findnext(s, w, tempPos)) >= 0)
        {
            tempPos = tempPos + w.length();
            counter++;
        }
        foundwords = new String[counter];
        wordcount = new int[counter];
        counter = 0;
        while ((tempPos = findnext(s, w, 0)) >= 0)
        {
            String foundWord = s.substring(0, tempPos);
            s = s.substring(tempPos + w.length());
            foundWordToArray(foundWord);
        }
        foundWordToArray(s);
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(String.format("Found word '%s' %d times.", foundwords[i], wordcount[i]));
        }
    }
    public static int findnext(String haystack, String needle, int startPos)
    {
        int hpos, npos;
        for (hpos = startPos; hpos < haystack.length()-needle.length(); hpos++)
        {
            for (npos = 0; npos < needle.length(); npos++)
            {
                if (haystack.charAt(hpos+npos)!=needle.charAt(npos))
                {
                    npos = needle.length()+1;
                }
            }
            if (npos == needle.length())
            {
                return hpos;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    private static int getIndexOfWord(String word, String[] foundwords)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < foundwords.length; i++)
        {
            if (word.equals(foundwords[i]))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    private static void foundWordToArray(String foundWord)
    {
        int IndexOfWord = getIndexOfWord(foundWord, foundwords);
        if (IndexOfWord < 0)
        {
            foundwords[counter] = foundWord;
            wordcount[counter] = 1;
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            wordcount[IndexOfWord]++;
        }
    }
}
```

i like this one:

```
public class repeat
{
    private static String[] foundwords = new String[0];
    private static int[] wordcount = new int[0];
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "Hello a world a this is a very good test to a a a a world just that contains just more words than just hello";
        String w = " ";
        int tempPos;
        while ((tempPos = findnext(s, w, 0)) >= 0)
        {
            String foundWord = s.substring(0, tempPos);
            s = s.substring(tempPos + w.length());
            foundWordToArray(foundWord);
        }
        foundWordToArray(s);
        for (int i = 0; i < foundwords.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(String.format("Found word '%s' %d times.", foundwords[i], wordcount[i]));
        }
    }
    private static void foundWordToArray(String foundWord)
    {
        int IndexOfWord = getIndexOfWord(foundWord, foundwords);
        if (IndexOfWord < 0)
        {
            String[] foundwordsTemp = new String[foundwords.length + 1];
            int[] wordcountTemp = new int[foundwords.length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(foundwords, 0, foundwordsTemp, 0, foundwords.length);
            System.arraycopy(wordcount, 0, wordcountTemp, 0, foundwords.length);
            foundwords = new String[foundwords.length + 1];
            wordcount = new int[wordcount.length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(foundwordsTemp, 0, foundwords, 0, foundwordsTemp.length);
            System.arraycopy(wordcountTemp, 0, wordcount, 0, foundwordsTemp.length);
            foundwords[foundwords.length-1] = foundWord;
            wordcount[foundwords.length-1] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            wordcount[IndexOfWord]++;
        }
    }
    public static int findnext(String haystack, String needle, int startPos)
    {
        int hpos, npos;
        for (hpos = startPos; hpos < haystack.length()-needle.length(); hpos++)
        {
            for (npos = 0; npos < needle.length(); npos++)
            {
                if (haystack.charAt(hpos+npos)!=needle.charAt(npos))
                {
                    npos = needle.length()+1;
                }
            }
            if (npos == needle.length())
            {
                return hpos;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    private static int getIndexOfWord(String word, String[] foundwords)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < foundwords.length; i++)
        {
            if (word.equals(foundwords[i]))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: another variant using "charAt" :